# How to click on img element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to access the below class in selenium but it shows element not found error.

Html

```
<button class="gpquestion-plusicon">
  <img src="./assets/images/viewdetails.png">
</button>
```

Code

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("//img[@src='./assets/images/viewdetails.png']").click()
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("//img[@src='./assets/images/viewdetails.png']").click()
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[@src='./assets/images/viewdetails.png']").click()
```

Exception

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: 
An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

Unfortunately none of them works. The xpath shows no element found error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are tring to use `xpath` as `css_selector`. Try

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[src='./assets/images/viewdetails.png']").click()
```

Or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='./assets/images/viewdetails.png']").click()
```

You can also use explicit wait

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[src='./assets/images/viewdetails.png']"))).click()
# or
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@src='./assets/images/viewdetails.png']"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I continue to get the below error:

I tried with both the options



    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//img[@src='./assets/images/viewdetails.png']"}
  (Session info: chrome=30.1.3441.120)